# Worklight: Average size of request from App to Server

Tags: performance, connection, ibm-mobilefirst

Sometimes i see a reconnect to WL server dialog box appears at the start-up of the App and sometimes it doesn't popup. My client has objection on this, they want to completely get rid of the "connection failure and re-try again...." message. I told them that sometimes due to weak signals this will happen.

Now he asks for:

1. Average size of request the device make and average size of response that goes back?
2. What bandwidth at minimum is required that must remain available on the network?

Kindly suggest on this, or anything i have to do like optimization :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to calculate an accurate average request/response size as it heavily depends on your application functionality.

If you want to disable the default connectivity failure behaviour (including the dialog) you need to specify your onConnectionFailure call back in initOptions. This way your callback function will be invoked instead of a default one and it is up to you to decide what should application behave like.

Comment: yes currently I am doing the same, I am showing my custom dialog box. BTW, any idea how many calls go at the App start-up? when we have connectOnStartup : true.   Thanks

Comment: You will have two requests - this is a standard WL app initialization flow. First request will get security challenges in response, second will answer them.

Comment: I see, but when App is initialized at that time it was not asked for challenge handle until user clicks on the Login or any action that triggers challenge handler mechanism. So why it is doing so :( can we stop this? and on user request it does it. Thanks

Comment: Not every challenge is user authentication related. First challenge  you get when initiating a new session with WL server is coming from antiXSRF realm. It is used to prevent cross site scripting attacks. You can read about it here - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en . Technically you can configure a security test without antiXSRF protection, but you must understand that this will make your apps vulnerable to this type of attacks.

Comment: just want to know that if i remove **connectOnStartup : true** then App will not connect with Server at startup, right? But will it be able to receive Direct Update? Thanks